# rails 4.1 can't deploy via capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-4.1, libyaml

i have very strange error when deploy my rails app with capistrano. sometimes it's deploy and sometimes not. 
for example i add something to css (just one string) e.g. `.my_some_class{width:10px}`
and after that deployment fails. before i add this - it's deploy ok.
i am sure what nothing else changed cause i make experimental commit which contain only one string of css.
my config:

```
rails 4.1.0
ruby 2.1.1p76

gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'capistrano-rvm', group: :development
gem 'capistrano-bundler', group: :development
```

end of deploy log:

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 137
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: SafeYAML Warning
  ----------------

  You appear to have an outdated version of libyaml (0.1.4) installed on your system.

  Prior to 0.1.6, libyaml is vulnerable to a heap overflow exploit from malicious YAML payloads.

  For more info, see:
  https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/03/29/heap-overflow-in-yaml-uri-escape-parsing-cve-2014-2525/

  The easiest thing to do right now is probably to update Psych to the latest version and enable
  the 'bundled-libyaml' option, which will install a vendored libyaml with the vulnerability patched:

  gem install psych -- --enable-bundled-libyaml



I, [2014-04-30T09:42:41.121037 #12193]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/default/releases/20140430134522/public/assets/Thumbs-82e32ea0cc1ce375db2805ceadd707ef.db
I, [2014-04-30T09:42:41.123108 #12193]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/default/releases/20140430134522/public/assets/agency_no_logo-a8544e60b8a38abeb431c2eb5089f7c6.png
I, [2014-04-30T09:42:41.461121 #12193]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/default/releases/20140430134522/public/assets/swipebox/img/loader-a66dde050b0b2447862919f2c4c37eda.gif

bash: line 1: 12193 Killed                  ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
```

Comment: Have you run `gem install psych -- --enable-bundled-libyaml`?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, it's not updating. also i'l try to load in gemfile gem 'psych', '>= 2.0.5'- no result

Comment: I have been seeing the same libyaml error recently on rails 4 / cap and have been ignoring it. It hasn't affected deployments. I will look into it eventually but have other issues. Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As was written above, probably, you have not enough RAM.

I solved problem by adding SWAP file on my Ubuntu 14.04 server:

Under the `root`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

Add next line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
 /swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

and:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
sudo chown root:root /swapfile 
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
```

check SWAP(maybe need reloading):

```
swapon -s
```

— [How To Add Swap on Ubuntu 14.04 @ Digital Ocean Community](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: thx! for me it's already solved as i written above, but it may be usefull, for someone else! i even mark you answer as correct)

Answer (score 13):

if someone have same error - problem was on hosting. server have not enough `ram(512mb)`, and process of compilation css/js was killed every time. than we change rate plan, which has 1gb ram, all deployed successfully. SO if you assets precompile failed - just try to add some resources to server. 
P.S. similar problem i found here [Capistrano deploy - assets precompile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162488/capistrano-deploy-assets-precompile-error)

Answer (score 6):

Try rebooting the server.Worked for me.

Comment: this work, cause after reboot you have more ram, than after a few days of work. for myself, i solved this problem long ago, but thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

> You appear to have an outdated version of libyaml

Update `libyaml`.