# Error while deploying to Unicorn server with capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I am getting following error while deploying to server.

```
DEBUG[50057f85] Command: cd /home/deploy/my_project/releases/20140901110633 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /home/deploy/my_project/shared/bin --path /home/deploy/my_project/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
DEBUG[50057f85]     bash: line 1:  5953 Killed                  ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /home/deploy/my_project/shared/bin --path /home/deploy/my_project/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bundle exit status: 137
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 137
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 107.170.240.115: bundle exit status: 137
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Quick help needed!!

Comment: Sounds like your SSH connection is messed up.  Can you SSH into this box?

Answer (score 6):

[rails 4.1 can't deploy via capistrano 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390311/rails-4-1-cant-deploy-via-capistrano-3)

Looks like not enough RAM on the server.  I just increased my RAM from 512MB to 1GB and I've passed this 137 error

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @iamthing answer. I had the same issue when I was trying to deploy my small site in Digital Ocean. I had done these following steps in order to  skip the error.

1.install the `htop` cpu monitoring software to check the `CPU` usage

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

2.Stop the unicorn web server process by

```
 ps aux | grep 'unicorn' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

3.Run `htop` to monitor the CPU usage

4.Try to deploy it again