# Capistrano version conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to upload my Rails app with:

```
bin/cap production deploy
```

but the deployment is failing with this error message:

```
You have requested:                                                                     
  capistrano ~> 3.3.0                                                                   

The bundle currently has capistrano locked at 3.7.1.                                    
Try running `bundle update capistrano`                                                  

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,                              
try passing them all to `bundle update`
```

I tried to fix the issue by running:

```
bundle update capistrano
```

but that did not solve it.

The thing I don't get is that I don't see where my application 'asks for capistrano 3.3.0'. In my Gemfile I set Capistrano to version 3.7.

Besides the capistrano gem I'm also using:

```
gem capistrano-rails, '~> 1.2'
gem capistrano3-delayed-job, '~> 1.3'
gem capistrano-figaro-yml
```

My Gemfile is at:

https://github.com/acandael/personalsite/blob/master/Gemfile

Does someone know how I can fix this Capistrano version issue?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: what is the content of your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Try to check your `confing/deploy.rb` to see if you have lock the capistrano version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow all the steps in the right order (don't skip any because you did it)

1. `cd` into your project directory
2. run `bundle exec gem uninstall capistrano -a` to remove all capistrano versions **from your bundle**
3. run `gem uninstall capistrano -a` to remove all capistrano versions **from your system**. Note that you may need to run this with root access if you get an error message
4. run `bundle install`
5. run `bundle exec gem list capistrano` which should output all installed gems with a name that contains "capistrano". You are supposed to have **only one version** of the *capistrano* gem
6. check in your files *config/deploy.rb* and *config/deploy/*.rb* if you have a `lock 3.x.x` instruction, and make sure it matches the install version as show in step 5
7. run cap in bundle context with `bundle exec cap production deploy` (use **exactly** this command line, do not use bin/cap)

Comment: I did all the steps. The error with capistrano 3.3.0 is gone. But now I'm getting this error: SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@146.185.164.246: bundle exit status: 137

Comment: Good, so you fixed the gem problem. This "bundle exit status: 137" error is unrelated.Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390311/rails-4-1-cant-deploy-via-capistrano-3 Or else open a new ticket.

Comment: yeah, it turned out that restarting the server fixed the bundle exit status: 137 error. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Should check config/deploy for the lock instruction as mentioned in step 6 before the other steps, I think - that alone fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try `bundle exec cap production deploy`

Comment: delete your gemfile.lock then bundle install and retry !

Comment: tried it, but get the same error message. The problem is that the error says I'm having capistrano 3.3.0 while the Gemfile.lock has version 3.7.1. But I can't find this version 3.3.0 in my Gemfile. Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe 3.7.1 is required as dependencies, run `gem list` to see the list of gem installed , and run `gem install capistrano -v 3.7.1`

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `YOUR_APP/.bindle` directory and run `bundle install` again

Comment: I removed the .bundle directory and than ran bundle install, but I'm still getting the same error message